# Three Finger gestures not working

Tags: gnome, gestures

In ubuntu 22.04LTS ,three finger gesture is not working,but two finger gestures (scroll) seems to be working fine. Please help me someone

Comment: It works for me in a Dell Precision M4800 with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS with Xorg (I switched from Wayland) and nvidia graphics with the built-in driver nouveau. Please specify what particular gestures, that do not work for you. For example I can use three-finger tapping to paste what is marked.

Comment: @sudodus the swipe up three finger gesture is not working, I can able to paste using three finger gesture.

Comment: What do you expect the swipe up three finger gesture to perform?

Comment: to see multi tabs

Comment: I never used that. Where does it work for you, @MadhanJ ? @ everybody: Does it work for you in any Ubuntu context?

Comment: I'm on a laptop and my 3 finger gesture to swipe left and right between activities wasn't working and found this discussion. What worked for me was restarting my computer. Hopefully you gesture works now and I would like to know what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

you have to do something like

In the file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf (to access it for editing, you could run

> sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

),
comment (add the leading #) this line
like

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

save and exit.

**NOTE :** This will stop screen sharing and screen recording if you need help on that comment.

Comment: But still the swipe up three finger gesture is not working

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the computer after you've made the changes?

Comment: thank you, it worked.
do you know why this happend ?
I never changed that config!

Comment: But why the hell can't them bot work? I have to choose between screen sharing and triple touch?